# Cant get Values from JSON Webservice

Tags: asp.net, ios, xcode, json, web-services

I have a Webservice, which picks Data from a Database ans send them in JSON to the Iphone

My Webservice:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
       [WebMethod]
       public string Person()
       {
           return Helper.Person();
       }
```

My Helper.cs

```
public class Helper
{
   internal static string Person()
   {
       List<object> person = new List<object>();

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=Localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BOOK-IT-V2;Integrated Security=true;"))
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT EMAIL FROM PERSON", con))
       {
           con.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               while (rdr.Read())
               {
                   if (rdr["EMAIL"] != DBNull.Value)
                   {
                       raumKlassenObject.Add(new {
                           Email=rdr["EMAIL"].ToString()});
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(person.ToArray());
   }
}
```

In Xcode:

```
  #import "RaumklasseViewController.h"

@interface RaumklasseViewController ()

@end

@implementation RaumklasseViewController
@synthesize result;
@synthesize dic;
@synthesize array;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) sendRequest:(NSString*)jsonText
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://ndqqxtsdsdoludwons-entwickludng.de/Webdiendst22/service1.asmx/Raumklasse"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData *reqData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonText UTF8String] length:[jsonText length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:reqData];
    NSURLResponse *response =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
    NSError* error;
    result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self sendRequest:@""];
    dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    self.array= [dic objectForKey:@"d"];

    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int n=0; n<[self.array count]; n++)
        [finalArray addObject:[[self.array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"Email"]];

}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];


}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    return [self.array count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;


}



@end
```

So far it works and my output is:

```
[{"Email":"abcd@web.de"},{"Email":"acsb@web.de"},{"Email":"asbd@gmx.de"},{"Email":"abcdw@web.de"},{"Email":"absds@web.de"}]
```

But if i try

```
self.array = [[dic objectForKey:@"d"] objectForKey:@"Email"];
```

to get only the values : abcd@web.de, acsb@web.de, asbd@gmx.de etc.

so iam getting an Error:

```
 [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a4ccb0.
```

I think that the Webservice is returning something wrong. , but i dont know what. Maybe you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries with one single key in each dictionary (`"Email"`).

`objectForKey:` is a method that returns the object for a key in a dictionary.

You can not call this method on the array that you are receiving from `[dic objectForKey:@"d"]` because this method does not work on arrays.

instead use `objectAtIndex:` like this:

```
self.array = [dic objectForKey:@"d"];
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int n=0; n<[self.array count]; n++)
    [finalArray addObject:[[self.array objectAtIndex:n] objectForKey:@"Email"]];
```

once that is done running `finalArray` will contain an array of strings of the email addresses only.

Comment: thx for your answer, i tried your solution, but now iam getting another error [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6841840

Comment: Did you define `array` as a string??

Comment: No i did not. @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;

Comment: Change it to a mutable array, because you are adjusting it.  Use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`

Comment: Is that the only place you define array?  Is it defined in the class definition as well?  Try using `(nonatomic, retain)` instead of `(strong, nonatomic)`  Only other thing I can think of is that your [dic objectForKey:@"d"] is returning a string.

Comment: no i just defined the array in the .h file.. Maybe the Problem ist coming from the Webservice?

Comment: Right, but did you define it above in the `{ ... }` or just as a property?

Comment: just as a property. I tried (nonatomic, retain) but still the sam error. I think the problem is in the webservice.

Comment: Well something is going wrong with your array because the error you are posting is because it is not seeing `array` as an NSArray, it is seeing it as a string and it is not finding the proper methods.  Without seeing all of your code it is hard to break down where that may be happening.

Comment: And if you put an `NSLog(%@,self.array);` right after `self.array = [dic objectForKey:@"d"];` what do you get on the console?

Comment: [{"Email":"abcd@web.de"},{"Email":"acsb@web.de"},{"Email":"asbd@gmx.de"},{"Email":"abcdw@web.de"},{"Email":"absds@web.de"}] like i posted in my Question.

Comment: i think i solved my problem. i changed my webservice to internal static Array Raumklasse() instead of internal static string Raumklasse()

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this:

```
[dic objectForKey@"d"]
```

Returns an array of dictionaries. Arrays cannot be accessed with objectForKey like your trying to here:

```
// the second objectForKey message is being sent to the array returned by the first objectForKey
[[dic objectForKey:@"d"] objectForKey:@"Email"];
```

However, valueForKey does work on arrays and returns a new array resulting from invoking valueForKey on each of the array's elements:

```
NSArray *objects = [dict objectForKey:@"d"];
NSArray *emails = [objects valueForKey:@"Email"];
```

This will get you all the email addresses in the array of dictionaries.

Comment: Wow, I did not know valueForKey would do that!  This must be the best method.

Comment: Getting in Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x6883a80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Name.'

Comment: post your definition of `array`

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array;